# what is the optimal system configuration for running Magento 2 EE on a laptop with xampv3.2.2

Tags: magento2.1.5, system-configuration, xampp

I need to work on Magento 2 EE and I have installed xamp 3.2.2 on windows 8.1 pro with 8GB RAM. I am on developer mode, cache is disabled and its running too slow, say it Admin login, frontend page load, and also the commands like

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile

php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

etc.,

Please tell what system configuration/hardware is recommended for this case.

Answer (score 0):

These are the configurations I have.

RAM : 16Gb

Storage : 256GB SSD

CPU : i7

Graphic Card : 2 GB (i dont think that really matters)

Before I had HDD but i placed SSD and saw significant speed improvements. because Magento does code generation and symlinks so read write operations are faster when we use SSD.